# Does an artist have a claim to the money generated from your IP?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

Does an artist have a claim to the money generated from your IP? Let's say that the design was written in paper and then the concept artist represented the written design graphically, does he own any portion of the IP? How can you make sure you don't face this problem if you hire an artist for your work?

Comment: The proper contract with the artist.

Comment: If the artist designed the "costume and everything" it's **not *your* IP**, it is theirs. Ideas are worth exactly the air they're made of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Depends if the artist is a contractor or an employee

> Let's say I am the person who created Spiderman, but my artist came up with the design of the costume and everything

Well, it certainly looks like you didn’t create Spider-Man - the artist did. If they are your employee then you, as their employer, own the copyright. If they are a contractor, then they own the copyright which can be transferred to you under the terms of the contract or otherwise.

> What if the design was written in paper and then the concept artist represented the written design graphically, does that make any difference?

Not really. Here the artist has created a derivative work but since they did so with your permission, that’s fine. The derivative work is a seperate work with its own copyright owned as stated above.

> How can you make sure you don't face this problem if you hire an artist for your work?

You set out in the contract who owns the copyright.

Comment: So if the design was written by me, I own the copyright. If not, then the artist owns it? Ok, then I need to make sure to keep the written design as evidence. If I have the written design, I don't need to get a copyright protection for it, correct?

Comment: @Sayaman no, you own the copyright in the words, the artist owns the copyright in the pictures.